# How do I make a page load while still running a PHP loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, web, loading

**On my website I have this PHP code:**

```php
 while(1) {
      sleep(1);
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
  $players = "0 Players";
} else if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
  $players = "1 Players";
} else if ($result->num_rows == 2) {
  $players = "2 Players";  
} else if ($result->num_rows == 3) {
  $players = "3 Players";  
} else if ($result->num_rows == 4) {
  $players = "4 Players";  
} else if ($result->num_rows == 5) {
  $players = "5 Players";  
} else if ($result->num_rows == 6) {
  $players = "6 Players";  
} else if ($result->num_rows == 7) {
  $players = "7 Players"; 
} else if ($result->num_rows == 8) {
  $players = "8 Players";  
} else if ($result->num_rows == 9) {
  $players = "9 Players";  
}
   }
```

The problem is that the page will not load. My guess is that the PHP loop needs to end before the page will load. However this needs to be running while the page is finished loading.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

And also if it helps the website is hosted. The host is NOT slow at all.

Comment: Why not just do `$players = $result->num_rows . " Players";`? Also what is the purpose of this loop?

Comment: this is an infinite cycle

Comment: Depending on the webserver, you *may* be able to use [`flush`](http://php.net/flush).

Comment: (but you should probably use a CLI script)

Comment: What part of the code should I flush? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Flushing somewhere within each iteration of the loop may keep the page alive. Possibly not, though, as this code doesn't output anything.

Comment: (It would be easier to advise you with a less contrived example. The code you've provided is simply silly to run infinitely... is there something you're looking to actually accomplish?)